# Google OAuth2.0 allows users NOT in list of test users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I'm developing a webapp which allows users to log in with their Google accounts, using OAuth2.0.
I've created an OAuth2.0 client ID, configured the OAuth consent screen with the Publishing status set to 'Testing', and added a test user.

The frontend of my app is built with React, and I'm using a package (react-google-login) to handle the flow. I can successfully sign in with the Google account I added as a test user, and retrieve the basic profile information needed.

The problem is I can also sign in with other Google accounts, which have not been added to the list of test users. I imagine that Google should simply not issue access tokens for accounts which are not in the list of test users.

I feel like I've misunderstood something about the OAuth process, or I have configured something incorrectly. I would appreciate if anyone had any pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is stored your list of test users? Which product do you use on Google Cloud? Cloud Identity Platform?

Comment: Have you used a GSuite enterprise account to create your application or are you using a gmail account?

Comment: I'm using a normal Gmail account. The list of test users is on the oauth consent screen configuration page (under APIs).

Comment: @Centaurian Did you find a solution to this issue? I also face the same problem with Google OAuth2.

Comment: @AugustoDestrero Unfortunately not.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here. I'm all over the place trying to figure it out.

Comment: We are also seeing this -- very troubling.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue too...did anyone find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is indeed bugged.

I was in the same spot as you, assuming I had misunderstood something. After reviewing my code over and over with no luck, I made a Stack Overflow post, in which I was advised to post to Google's bug tracking system. After doing some troubleshooting with Google they confirmed the bug, and they are now working to fix it (for a little while already).

I included this thread as an example when talking to Google. I meant to post an update here after getting in touch with them, but I forgot, sorry!

The buganizer thread with more details:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211370835

Comment: this is confusing, its already more than a year this bug not fixed

Comment: I think the bug is the documentation, and the behavior is intended. They appear to accept this as a bug, but it's a little ambiguous, and I have a hunch that the Google person in that thread doesn't fully understand. Or they do now, but nobody bothered updating the issue. I have posted more details in a separate answer and in the issue, but it suffices to say that the publishing process doesn't make sense for sites that only use Google for login, and those sites remain unpublished and will break if Google changes this. Google should make this all more obvious.

Answer (score 5):

I don't work for Google and, because the documentation is confusing, this answer isn't definitive, but fairly certain:

The bug is in the interface and the documentation, not the behavior. They are unlikely to change the behavior. When I try to "Publish" my app it requires me to tell them why I "need access to sensitive and/or restricted user data". My app (and yours, it appears) don't ask for anything that Google defines as sensitive or restricted, which means that we can't publish. In your case, you don't want to publish because your site is (or was) still in development. In my case, my site is live and currently using Google Sign-In, but I *can't* "publish" (as they define it), because I don't ask for sensitive information and therefore cannot describe what I'm going to do with it. If Google were to change the behavior on their side, sites like mine would stop working.

What is confusing is that the "publish" status is (probably) not intended as a way to secure your app, it is intended as a way to secure their users' information. In other words, when they prevent non-test accounts from logging in, they're preventing you from getting access to user information, not preventing users from gaining access to your site. When you publish you have to verify that you should be allowed to have this access. If you're not asking for sensitive information, they don't have to protect their users from logging in.

If they want me to publish, I'll gladly do so as soon as they make it possible. (As it is, the whole thing makes me nervous and I've contemplated requesting access to some trivial "sensitive" thing just so that I can complete the verification process and be "published", but I'm worried that this will prevent some users from logging in, and also I just don't like having unnecessary user information.)

In other words, you should lock down your app from your side. And Google should stop calling this status "published" and "testing", and document things more consistently. They should email people whose apps are (unexpectedly) allowing people to login because of this, and give them the option to easily turn that access off.

I feel a little bit like being that guy who says that you shouldn't depend on settings such as these to prevent people from accessing your app. To some extent "that guy" has a good point, however, it's understandable that people expect a setting to do what it literally says it will do, even if it also says it won't do it in other places.

This answer is more-or-less what I wrote in the issue that somebody else opened on this subject: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211370835#comment33. Hopefully Google can confirm or deny my interpretation and possibly even improve the way they deal with this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you're only asking for the **email** scope?

It appears the test user filter and possibly the whole concept of the 'app' being in test mode exists only inside the consent screen feature.

For some reason, Google doesn't show the consent screen if you only ask for email.

So... maybe that means you don't need a consent screen, and therefore don't need to care what that feature thinks about your app (that your app is in test mode and needs to be verified before going into production).

Or maybe it's a bug? Or maybe just because you can do this doesn't mean it's allowed by Google's terms. Maybe they just haven't implemented preventing that use case.

Anyway, it may help you to know that if you add a more significant scope like the Calendar API then the following things will change:

- Non-test users will get a message like "The developer hasn’t given you access to this app." and won't be able to complete oauth
- Test users will get a message like "Google hasn't verified this app"
- Test users will see a consent screen

Basically, everything starts working as expected.

By the way, just putting "email" or "profile" for scope seems to be an old way of doing things, and all the newer scopes want you to use a full URL for the scope (despite google themselves not using the full URL when you're configuring your scopes).

For example, if you want the email and calendar scopes, you can put this value for your `scope` field:

```
email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
```

Or you can use this equivalent value:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
```

Not suggesting you add a scope like email for the sake of it, just that it sheds light on what's happening, and if there's a scope like that that you need anyway, adding it will solve your problem.